# Monte Carlo Integration

Tags: integration, monte-carlo

I was reading this [document](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs294-13/fa09/lectures/scribe-lecture4.pdf) (I will reproduce the equation):

```
Monte Carlo Integration
Ravi Ramamoorthi
http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs294-13/fa09/lectures/scribe-lecture4.pdf
```

In which you can find the following series of equations to compute the expected value of the random variable of the integral: $F_n = {(b-a) \over n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i)$.

Here at the equations:

$\begin{array}{l}
E[F_n] &=& E\left[{(b-a) \over n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i)\right]\\
&=&{(b-a) \over n}\sum_{i=1}^n E[f(X_i)]\\
&=&{(b-a) \over n}\sum_{i=1}^n \color{\red}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)p(x)dx}\\
&=&{(b-a) \over n}{1 \over (b-a)}\color{\green}{\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx}\\
&=&{1 \over n} \sum_{i=1}^n\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\\
&=&I.
\end{array}$

So what I don't understand in these equations is how we go from $ E[f(X_i)]$ to $\color{\red}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)p(x)dx}$ and then from an integral from - to + infinity to an integral from a to b (by taking out p(x) which is the probability density function): $\color{\green}{\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx}$.

It would be great if someone could tell me where these substitutions come from.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It seems that, perhaps, that the $X_i$ are uniform random variables on the interval $(a,b)$? In that case $E[f(X_i)] = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x)dx$ since if $p(x)$ is the density of $X_i$ then $$ p(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{b-a} & x \in (a,b) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ So, the question is, what are the $X_i$?

Comment: Thank you Tom. My question is more how to you go from $E[f(X_i)]$ to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)p(x)dx $. I don't understand this bit, the indefinite integral or equating this expected value with the indefinite integral.

Comment: I'm not sure what the $X_i$ are, but it is true that if $X$ is any continuous random variable (taking values in $\mathbb{R}$) with density $p(x)$, then for "nice enough" functions $f$, $$E[f(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) p(x) dx$$.